# Alternative to setTimeout that doesn't stop running after program has been stopped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot that has a Mute and Tempban command. Problem is, the only way I can figure out how to unmute or unban after awhile is with setTimeout. Problem with setTimeout is that it stops after I stop the program. I can't really have this, because the bot may crash, or I would have to stop it to implement new things, etc. I've looked into something like cron BUT I feel like that won't work.

```js
            switch (checkTime) {
              case true:
                member.roles.add(mutedRole);
                muteEmbed.addField(
                  `${member.user.tag} was muted by ${message.author.username} for an undefined time.`,
                  `Reason: ${muteReason}.`
                );
                break;
              default:
                member.roles.add(mutedRole);
                muteEmbed.addField(
                  `${member.user.tag} was muted by ${message.author.username}.`,
                  `Muted for ${muteTimeRaw}.`
                );
                setTimeout(() => {
                  member.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
                }, mutedTime);
            }
```

this is what I have so far. What options do I have?

In short, how can I have it run a command like `message.guild.unban('member')`, where member is different every time, and have it, for example, run that 3 days later, even if the program has stopped and started?

Comment: You cannot do that within a Node program. The best you could probably do is to establish a `cron` job or something like that, external to Node, and have that perform the operation, but that's non-trivial.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cron jobs, and the experiences I've had with them weren't really the best. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The answer depends on your operating system. If a Node program stops, it stops; there's no trace of it left on the system. Making some sort of system request to schedule the execution of *another* program is pretty much your only choice, but that's complicated and has all sorts of complications of its own (like, what if your bot changes its mind about revoking the ban?). This question is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use enmap, its basically a discord.js Collection, but it saves across runs